# not receiving keyup events

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Browser: Chrome 8.0.552.224
jQuery: 1.4.2

I have a DIV that I've assigned a tabindex to.  I'm trying to determine when someone hits CTRL-Z or CTRL-Y when that DIV has focus.  I am able to handle keydown events, but keyup events never fire.  Any idea why?  Perhaps there is a better way to detect CTRL-Z or CTRY-Y?

Comment: $(somediv).keyup(function() { /*something*/ } );

Comment: @user: *all* your code.  The key down, the key up code.  We're just stabbing blindly in the dark without it.  You can edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out that, if you set a breakpoint on a keydown event in the Chrome developer tools javascript console, the corresponding keyup event is never sent.  So, use console.log instead of breakpoints to debug keyup/keydown events.